# Execute mysql without sudo

Tags: mysql, mariadb, sudo

I am trying to install wordpress on Odroid C2.
However, wordpress could not access mysql.

[image]

So, I tried this.

[image]

If I execute mysql with sudo, it is OK. But, without sudo, I can't.

The OS of C2 is Ubuntu Mate 16.04, so I installed mariaDB instead of mysql.

I followed the guide of mariaDB installation.

How can I use mysql without sudo, and how can my wordpress access the DB.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "Wordpress could not access mySQL". Wordpress won't care what user mySQL runs at; it will access mysQL through its own native protocol. What error are you getting when trying to run mySQL as non-root?

Comment: @Morgan there's two levels at play here: the system's users, and mySQL's. At the moment, he seems to be struggling with the former.

Comment: Perhaps someone more knowledgeable than me can give you a full answer, but for reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/changing-mysql-user.html It appears that running mySQL as root is discouraged.

Comment: the only reason is that you not have permission to login as root in the DB. Login and grant your privileges to to user

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be an serverfault.com issues. But anyway, go through this checklist

1. Are you starting mysql with port other than 3306
2. Check access of mysql client is o+rx , i.e. ls -la /usr/bin/mysql
3. Did you grant user access other than "root" in mysqldb/mariadb. Mysql db may prevent you from using root@localhost if it is not running sudo

So if in case no 3, you must create a new user and grant access to it to solve this. i.e.

```
GRANT ALL ON <YOUR_WP_DATABASE_NAME>.* TO "wpuser"@"localhost" IDENTIFIED BY "somepassword";
```

Afterwards, try mysql using that user to confirm it works.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It works for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

try this to solve the problem:

Login in your DB

```
sudo mysql -u root -p
```

then make these modifications:

```
MariaDB []>use mysql;
MariaDB [mysql]>update user set plugin='' where User='root';
MariaDB [mysql]>flush privileges;
MariaDB [mysql]>exit
```

try login again without sudo

Comment: Thank you for your attention. I tried it, but I cannot still access.

Comment: Cannot connect after that, even in `sudo`.

Comment: Same problem, when I try: update user set plugin='' where User='root'; I get error... ERROR 1356 (HY000): View 'mysql.user' references invalid table(s) or column(s) or function(s) or definer/invoker of view lack rights to use them